# OWL carousel stacking images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel-2

So im currently building a website and im having an issue with OWL Carousel, it seems like the images are stacking above eachother when changing image on the slider, resulting in a huge blank space.

Error can be seen here : [www.hissey-data.co.uk](https://hissey-data.co.uk)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I have provided the code below.

**OWL Carousel Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-banner").owlCarousel({
      nav : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      items: 1,
      singleItem: true,
      dots:false,
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="owlWrapper">
    <div id="owl-banner" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><img src="images/Banner.png" alt="slider 1"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/Banner.png" alt="slider 2"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/Banner.png" alt="slider 3"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

```
.owlWrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#owl-banner .item img{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.owl-item.active .caption {
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}

.owl-nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 45%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.owl-nav button {
    background-color: rgb(179, 20, 2) !important;
    border-radius: 0% !important;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px !important;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.owl-nav button.owl-next {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 100%;
}

.owl-nav button span {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

.owl-nav button:hover {
    background: rgb(86, 13, 5) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your project you may forget to add these 2 things.

- `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>`
- `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Try to add this. you can see running example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-banner").owlCarousel({
    nav: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    items: 1,
    singleItem: true,
    dots: false,
  });
});
```

```css
.owlWrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#owl-banner .item img {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.owl-item.active .caption {
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.owl-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.owl-nav button {
  background-color: rgb(179, 20, 2) !important;
  border-radius: 0% !important;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px !important;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.owl-nav button.owl-next {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}

.owl-nav button span {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.owl-nav button:hover {
  background: rgb(86, 13, 5) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="owlWrapper">
  <div id="owl-banner" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x450.png?text=slider1" alt="slider 1"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x450.png?text=slider2" alt="slider 2"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x450.png?text=slider3" alt="slider 3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already have the files in stored locally.

`<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/imageReel.js"></script>
<script src="owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You also have `owl.carousel.min.css` ?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.carousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">`

Yes, these are stored in the header.

Comment: Hello, i found the issue, OWL uses a .active class, i was also using one for my navigation bar. Once i changed the class names it worked as intended. Thanks for the help though. Hope you have a great day :D